# Ajax call is inserting data on page in some other place

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making use of ajax call to insert data in starting of my page. this is more like a wall post script. Whenever user posts something, the latest post is shown in the top of the posts page.

I am using JS, PHP and an HTML page.

here is my js code:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#tweet_submit").click(function() 
    {
    var tweet = $("#tweet").val();
    var x = $('.preview').attr('id');
    if(x)
    var z= x;
    else
    var z=0;
    var dataString = 'tweet='+ tweet+ '&z=' +z;

    if(tweet=='')
    {
    alert('Please type your tweet here');
    }
    else
    {
    alert('into post');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WallPost/post_tweet1.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#tweet").val('');
    $("#preview").hide();
    $("#content").prepend(html);
    }
    });
    }return false;
    }); 
    });
```

This is my PHP page:
post_tweet.php

```
    <?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("session.php");
    include_once 'includes/time_stamp.php';

    //echo "request sent to post";

    if($_POST)
    {

    $tweet=$_POST['tweet'];
    $upload_id=$_POST['z'];
    $time=time();

    $query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,time,upload_id,uid_fk) VALUES ('$tweet','$time','$upload_id','$uid')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
                                {
                                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                $msg ="<br> 1 record added";
                                }

    echo "<br>".$msg;
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select T.tid, T.tweet, T.time, T.upload_id, U.username, U.fullname, U.email FROM tweets T, users U WHERE T.uid_fk=U.uid and T.uid_fk='$uid' order by T.tid DESC LIMIT 1");
    //$show_result=mysqli_query($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($sql))
    {
    echo "data start here";
    $tid= "$row[0]";
    $tweet= "$row[1]";
    $time = "$row[2]";
    $img_id= "$row[3]";
    $username="$row[4]";
    $fullname = "$row[5]";
    $email = "$row[6]";
    $lowercase = strtolower($email);
    $imagecode = md5( $lowercase );

    $image_sql=mysqli_query($con,"select image_name from uploads where upload_id='$img_id'");
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_row($image_sql))
    {
    $image_name="$data[0]";
    $chars = 7; 

            $text = $image_name." "; 
            $text = substr($text,0,$chars);  
            $imgtext = "pic.twitter/".$text."...";

    }
    //echo "<div class='center'>";
    echo "<div class='tweet_box' id='$tid'>";
    echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$imagecode?s=50'></div>";
    echo "<div class='tweet_body'>";
    ?>
    <div class='tweet_time'><?php time_stamp($time);?></div>
    <?php
    echo "<div><b><a href='http://twitter.com/$username'>$fullname</a></b> <span class='uname'>@$username</span></div>";
    echo "<div class='tweet_text'>$tweet &nbsp;";
    if($img_id!=0)
    {
    echo "<a href=''/>$imgtext</a></div>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "<div class='tweet_options'><div class='first_option'><a href='#'>Expand</a> </div><div class='sub_options'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Reply</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Retweet</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#'>Favourite</a></div></div>";

    if($img_id!=0)
    {

    ?>
    <div class="tweet_image" id="tweetimage<?php echo $tid; ?>">
    <center><img src="uploads/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" class="image_show"/></center></div>

    <?php
    }

    echo "</div></div>";
    ?>

    <div class="tweet_reply_box" id="replybox<?php echo $tid;?>">
    <div><textarea rel="<?php echo $tid;?>" id="replytext<?php echo $tid;?>" class="reply" name="reply" 

    maxlength="140">@<?php echo $username;?> </textarea></div>

    <div class="reply_button_bar" id="replybutton<?php echo $tid;?>">
    <div><input type="submit"  value=" Reply " class="reply_btn" id="<?php echo $tid;?>"/></div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="reply_load<?php echo $tid;?>" class="reply_load">

    </div>


    <?php
    }

    }
    else { }
    ?>
```

And this is my HTML page:

Wallpost.php

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Design Modo - Code-pal | eCommerce Website Template - Dead Stocker</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.code-pal.com/wp-content/themes/codpeal-new/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/check_style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wallpost/wtfdiary.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wallpost/tipsy_title.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WallPost/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WallPost/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
        <script src="WallPost/js/twitter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WallPost/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="body-contents">
            <?php include("left-body1.php"); ?>
            <div class="center">
                <br>
                    <div class="txthead"><strong>Share thoughts here</strong></div>
                <?php
                    include("WallPost/index.php");
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include("right-body.php"); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- eo .body-content -->
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </div><!-- eo .page-wrap-->
```

Here is the code where i post tweet:

index.php under WallPost folder:

```
    <?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("session.php");
    include("includes/time_stamp.php");
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wtfdiary.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tipsy_title.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="container">

    <div id="sidebar_container">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <div id='logo'><img src='images/1.png'></div>

    <div id="box">

    <div><textarea id="tweet" name="tweet" placeholder="Compose new Tweet..."></textarea></div>

    <div id='preview'></div>
    <div id="button_bar">
    <div id="icons">
    <div class="filebutton" title="Image Upload">
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajax_image.php'>
    <span><input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg"/></span>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit"  value=" Tweet " class="btn" id="tweet_submit"/></div>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="main">  -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id='heading'>Tweets</div>
    <div id='content'>

    <?php include("loads_tweets1.php");?>

    <!-- </div>  -->
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

So after i make use of all these code, Post is shown in my page, but the way it is shown is not correct.

The post is inserted at some random place. (I couldn't attach image due to less reputation)

Can someone please tell what is going wrong, and i am not able to get this data in correct place where my other posts are listed.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It seems like the content is inserted at the top of the `#content` element

Comment: Pffffff seriously, that's like 250 lines of code, and the javascript and HTML are not even indented. Help us help you : narrow down the code and indent it please...

Answer (score 0):

Your input helped me and i was able to solve it. Content was being called at two places, and ajax inserted the data on first location and i was not getting it placed where i needed it.

Thanks.